# How to manage arrays from custom functions stored in functions.php?

Tags: functions, actions, array

In functions.php I have made the following code:

```
add_action( 'listofnames', 'SomeNames' );

function SomeNames(){

$names=array( "john","edgar","miles");
return $names;

}
```

It should return array I wish to manipulate with, but when in index.php I try, it goes wrong. Obviously it does not work this way:

```
do_action('listofnames');
foreach (do_action('listofnames') as $n){

echo $n;
}
```

Can anybody help me to manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A callback for an action doesn't return anything, because that return value is never passed through by WordPress.

Use a filter instead:

```
add_filter( 'listofnames', 'SomeNames' );

function SomeNames() {

    $names=array( "john","edgar","miles");
    return $names;
}
```

And in your template you call it like this:

```
$names = apply_filters( 'listofnames', [] );

foreach ( $names a $name ) {
    echo $name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!